# Cannot install the XCRUN built IPA on IPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, xcrun

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?.

I am using the following command to generate the ipa from a cordova project :

```
 'xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v  "/Users/user/Downloads/CordovaPrj/platforms/ios/build/device/App Name.app" -o "/Users/user/Downloads/CordovaPrj/release/ios/App_Name_1.0.0.ipa"  --embed "/Users/user/Downloads/CordovaPrj/build.tools/App_Name_DEV.mobileprovision" --sign "iPhone Distribution: Company Name (B56QVK65GU)"'
```

I can get the generated IPA file but when I try to install the IPA on the device it gets stuck at the "installing...".

And the icon gets greyed out.

My guess is that the provisioning profile is not properly embedded in this one.

Also I can gurantee that the uuid of the device I am trying to install on is in the : App_Name_DEV.mobileprovision provisioning profile.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

also I have provided my build log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85vUqBPKLOxUGwzdXpPSE90WkE/edit?usp=sharing).

The only error I could capture is during the ipa installtion using the "IPhone configuration Utility" which is given below :

```
Jul  9 11:08:44 Rameshs-iPhone librariand[102] <Error>: ubiquity account is not configured (or is disabled for this client), not creating collection

Jul  9 11:08:44 Rameshs-iPhone librariand[102] <Error>: error in _handle_client_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/10/Unable to configure the collection.
```

Comment: renmae .ipa with .zip and check the embedded provisional profile. It will give you clue that is it using the same pp or not.

Comment: when I extract the .zip I could only see the Payload folder. Inside which I can seee this app file. does this mean that the provisioning profile is not included ?. or does the provisioning profile get embedded inside the app file ?

Comment: But then I r'clicked on the .app file and selected "show package contents" then I could see the "embedded.mobileprovision" inside the app folder. But still I can't install on the device. Could you please help ?.

Comment: Now check if your device uuid is present in that embedded.mobileprovision?

Comment: yes it is I can 100% guarantee that.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this by chance?  I am having this exact problem and it is very frustrating!